# Remove colored lines on XML edditor

Tags: android-studio

I don't know why but the empty lines on the xml editor of android studio are colored dark green, could you please tell me how to remove this feature?

Also, there is black square box on the start of the line 88 (see photo), could you please tell me what it is?

Thank you very much in advance..![image: ![enter image description here][Colored Lines]

Comment: I don't know what's the exact problem but at line no 88 it's color preview for hexadecimal color code that is #000000. By clicking on that box you can change the color.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.! I get what the black box is.. But i cannot make those green lines disappear.. They are really annoying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found how to disable it. Preferences -> Editor -> Color & Fonts search for Injected language fragment and uncheck background.

edit: I have found another question similar with this one: The exact answer was: The green lines show areas interpreted by IDE as different language injection.

In those areas you end up with different code completion rules etc.

So assuming you used the language injections by mistake, clicking the lightbulb and choosing "Un-inject Language/Reference" removes those areas.

It's quicker than going through the settings and prevents any inconsistent highlighting and code completion when editing the file later.